# powershell "Get-Volume" command finish with error

Tags: powershell

I try to create disk used moniter script using powershell.
In my script I use `Get-Volume` command to check total size of volume. I register this script in the task scheduler and run it through task. Then I run task, my script finish with following error.

error:

```
TerminatingError(Get-Volume): "The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: No MSFT_Volume objects found with property 'DriveLetter' equal to 'f'.  Verify the value of the property and retry."

C:\DIVA\Script\DataDiskUsedChecker\DiskUsed.ps1 : Microsoft.PowerShell.Cmdletization.Cim.CimJobException: No
MSFT_Volume objects found with property 'DriveLetter' equal to 'f'.  Verify the value of the property and retry.
At C:\DIVA\Script\DataDiskUsedChecker\DiskUsed.ps1:77 char:5
+     Write-Error $_.Exception
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,DiskUsed.ps1
```

But once I run `Get-Volume` command with my powershell terminal window and run task again, then task finish successfully.

it will be appreciated if anyone give me advice to fix this.

code:

```
try {
    Start-Transcript -Path "$PSScriptRoot\DiskUsed.log"

    #set exection preference
    $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

    #Get Total
    $length = (Get-Volume -DriveLetter f).Size
    $DiskTotal = New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{Name = "DiskTotal"; Size = $length ; Rate = "-"; Discription = "Total disk size" }

    #Get DiskFree and DiskUsed
    $data = Get-PSDrive -Name F
    $DiskUsed = $data.Used
    $DiskFree = $data.Free

    $UsedRate = "{0:0.00}" -f ($DiskUsed / $DiskTotal.Size * 100)
    $FreeRate = "{0:0.00}" -f ($DiskFree / $DiskTotal.Size * 100)

    $DiskUsed = New-Object PSObject -Property @{ Name = "DiskUsed"; Size = "$DiskUsed" ; Rate = "${UsedRate}%"; Discription = "Total amount of disk space used" }
    $DiskFree = New-Object PSObject -Property @{ Name = "DiskFree"; Size = "$DiskFree" ; Rate = "${FreeRate}%"; Discription = "available disk size" }

    #Get DataTransfer
    $length = (Get-ChildItem F:\10_DataTransfer -Recurse -Force | Measure-Object Length -Sum).sum
    $Rate = "{0:0.00}" -f ($length / $DiskTotal.Size * 100)
    $DataTransfer = New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{Name = "DataTransfer Prod"; Size = $length ; Rate = "${Rate}%" ; Discription = "Total amount of Under DataTransfer folder" }

    #Get Data
    $length = (Get-ChildItem F:\04_Data -Recurse -Force | Measure-Object Length -Sum).sum
    $Rate = "{0:0.00}" -f ($length / $DiskTotal.Size * 100)
    $Data = New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{Name = "Data"; Size = $length ; Rate = "${Rate}%" ; Discription = "Total amount of Under Data folder" }

    #Get WORK
    $length = (Get-ChildItem F:\WORK -Recurse -Force | Measure-Object Length -Sum).sum
    $Rate = "{0:0.00}" -f ($length / $DiskTotal.Size * 100)
    $WORK = New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{Name = "WORK"; Size = $length ; Rate = "${Rate}%" ; Discription = "Total amount of Work folder" }

    #Get AppUsed
    $length = (Get-ChildItem f: | Where-Object { $_.Name -notin "04_Data", "10_DataTransfer", "WORK" } | Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force | Measure-Object Length -Sum).Sum
    $Rate = "{0:0.00}" -f ($length / $DiskTotal.Size * 100)
    $AppUsed = New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{Name = "AppUsed"; Size = $length ; Rate = "${Rate}%" ; Discription = "Application install size" }

    #Output result to CSV file
    $Result = @()
    $Result += $DiskUsed
    $Result += $AppUsed
    $Result += $DataTransfer
    $Result += $Data
    $Result += $WORK 
    $Result += $DiskFree
    $Result += $DiskTotal 
    $Result | Select-Object Name, Size, Rate, Discription | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Out-File "$PSScriptRoot\DataDiskUsed.csv"

    Stop-Transcript
}
catch {
    Write-Error $_.Exception
    Stop-Transcript
    exit 1
}
```

thanks

Comment: can you post the line of code inside you script?

Comment: what happens when you run the entire script manually, under the account context for the scheduled task?

Comment: I added my code. The line `$length = (Get-Volume -DriveLetter f).Size` returns error.

Comment: When I run this script manually with an account for the scheduled task, that complete successfully. And when I set task user "Bultin\SYSTEM" , this error never happens. task user is non admin account. But and I do not think I need to add Administrator privileges to the task user.

Comment: The user that runs the task apparently has no mapping for drive `F`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WMI maybe. Works for me.

```
$diskD = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $env:computername -Filter "DeviceID='D:'" | Select-Object Size,FreeSpace

    $diskDSize = [math]::Round($diskD.Size/1GB, 2)
    $diskDFreeSpace = [math]::Round($diskD.FreeSpace/1GB, 2)
```

Comment: I don't know what is wrong with `get-volume` command through, WMI worked for me too. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Check to see if the service "Microsoft Storage Spaces SMP" is disabled.

It should be set to manual.

My bet is someone's optimization script/app/utility set it to disabled. In my case, it was due to VMware's OS Optimization Tool.

Comment: This is what the issue was for me - an admin shutdown the service with Group Policy.